# GCC error after switching from 32 to 64 bit machine

Tags: gcc

I had functional code that compiled and ran on a 32 bit fedora 17 machine. Recently we had to switch the host computer to a 64 bit Centos machine and I am encountering new difficulties compiling the code. When I type 'make' I get the following error message:

```
xdatalog> sudo make
gcc -o xdatalog -march=i686 -ffast-math -O3  -I /FedoraBackup/opt/uhd/host/include  xprocess_data.o xdatalog.o pentek_setup.o xget_input.o create_datafile.o xheader.o xtimepos.o xpol_ctrl.o xdechirp.o  attitude.o -lfftw3f_threads -lfftw3f -lm -lpthread -luhd
xprocess_data.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you've simply left some old 32-bit object files lying around, which clearly can't be linked into a 64-bit binary. In this particular case, the file `xprocess_data.o`.

Try removing all the old object files and recompile from scratch (I don't know about your build process, but `make clean` should normally do it, if it isn't something very custom.)